# setting alternative img source

Tags: html, image

i have a web app written in aspx.

I have a img control.

If a required image is not available then the alt text message displays.

Is there a way to set an 'alt image' instead?  This img control relies on updates so after a default period of 10 seconds if no image is acquired then I would like to set a default image instead.  It would be handy if there was a property like 'alt image'.

I guess I could use a timer to check but would be interested in other approaches.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onerror attribute can execute js and set a new image like shown below

```
<img src="/images/200.png" onerror="this.src='/images/404.png'" >
```

Comment: lovely. I should have thought of that too :)

Comment: got to wait 9 mins to accepet